# Which profile's security setting does email template adhere to

Tags: email-template, security

I am sending out an email template which has a line looks like this:

```
DFV Request: {!Ida_Hearing__c.Domestic_and_Family_Violence_Matter_Text__c}
```

Interestingly, this field doesn't show in my email template. It is blank. This is a formula which whose formula looks like below:

```
IF(Domestic_and_Family_Violence_Matter__c , 'Yes', 'No')
```

I have did a query in query editor on that record and the returned result has no issue. It displays No.

I am wondering what is the reason that caused this issue. I have set Domestic_and_Family_Violence_Matter_Text__c field level security visible to every profile. But there can be hidden ones I don't see though. What is the possible reason behind this?

Comment: Templates are picky when it comes to cross object fields. Create a formula on the idea hearing object to pull in the field from the lookup record. Use this new field in the template. I bet the value will show then. Also regular WFR run in system context as do the merge fields.

Comment: @Eric there is no lookup field in he email template. Or otherwise I don't see that?

Comment: disregard. I misread

Comment: @Eric, I don't quite understand that. But I have a feeling that it is probably the reason. Would you please make an answer of it?